# Change number of completed builds on web site?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, build-server

The **Completed Build** section in our TFS 2013 installation only shows.. recent builds ..when clicking on a build definition.
Not even sure what criteria I would use but it seems everything older than a day is scrapped.

*However*, picking **a particular** build from the build definition or the little green-red-bar graph on the left  (ok/failed builds) always displays the information.

So is there a way to configure the number of recent builds shown on the web page when selecting the **build definition**?

Having an empty list of builds there confused developers no too comfy with the TFS server and most don't bother clicking on the bar graph on the left to browse to a particular build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it not just a case of using the drop down in the top right of the screen to display longer time periods?

[image: Display completed builds for different time periods]

Comment: ugh - looks like it! Is there a way to set a default for that drop down?

Comment: I'll look, but the concept behind this is to speed up the screen, and to show only the latest builds.

Comment: it looks to be set in js at the follwoing location C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\_static\tfs\12\_scripts\TFS\min\Build\Scripts. I provide no waranty if you look into this much further. i would just get your team to click the drop down, It defaults to Today, which obviously is the most recent build, you can then select the time period with which to look into past builds